# Java Swing brief paintComponent graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am creating a java 2D game and have come to a point where I am thinking of creating "pop-up graphics" i.e graphics that will populate the screen when a certain event occurs. Say, you pick up a certain item, I want this item to be displayed in the middle of the screen in a box containing information about said item.

Currently I have one big paintComponent that paints all of the graphics for the game (tiles, entities, players etc (which has been done efficiently I might add)). I know that I can probably have a boolean value which checks if an item has been picked up in that method, but it feels wrong.

What I am wondering is, is there a way for items to have their own paintComponent so that when it is called, it will show say a bo for a brief period WITHOUT having a boolean value in the big paintComponent method that I currently use for everything?

Small code example (won't execute)

```
public class popUpGraphics extends (JComponent or JPanel or whatever works best for this scenario)
{
    public popUpGraphics(){
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       //g.Draw(stuff);
    }
}
```

and then somewhere in an event I instantiate this or somesuch.
I do not want this to override the other paintcomponent, I just want to add to it
(as if it was another layer) to the paintComponent

In short I want to know:
 1. Is is possible to have brief graphics shown without including in the huge paintComponent method
2. What Swing library should be extended (JComponent, JPanel etc)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, a boolean value which checks if an item has been picked up is exactly what you should be doing.  Paint methods should use object states to decide what to paint.

Comment: so that is the conventional method? Fair enough. I mean that's what I have been doing so far, just thought there was a different, "better" way. Thanks